# An installation of owncloud requires 12.04 server but mine is not stated as"server"

Tags: server, apache2

I am a super newbie so I hope this is not a stupid question but what will I need to qualify to run this software package? I've installed openssh and apache2 and they work fine so I think many of the server attributes may be on my system but how might my system yet be lacking?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you installed the desktop or server edition. More details are in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Owncloud can be run on a server or desktop installation. Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop can both be configured to do the same things.

Depending on how you're planning on installing Owncloud, you shouldn't need to install anything extra. The installer should take care of installing dependencies.